# Vim ignoring ftplugin?

Tags: vim, filetype

I have created the file `/usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin/rb.vim` with the following contents;

```
set ts=2 " Set tab size to 2
set bs=2 " Suggested for ruby
set sw=2 " Suggested for ruby
set et   " Convert tabs into spaces
set fdm=marker " Enable code block folding
```

The contents of my `/etc/vim/vimrc` is the following;

```
syntax on " Enable syntax highlighting
set number " Enable line numbers
set ts=4 " Set tab width to 4 spaces
set nocompatible " Disable compatibility mode (prevent ABCD key bugs)
colorscheme kolor " Set the color scheme

filetype plugin on " Enable filetype plugins (from http://bit.ly/GVfznk)
```

I added the `filetype plugin on` line from [this](http://bit.ly/GVfznk) superuser question, but it doesn't seem to change anything. I can confirm the loading of the `/etc/vim/vimrc` file, as when typing `:filetype`, the line `filetype detection:ON plugin:ON indent:OFF` is returned, showing that it has worked.

Running `:scriptnames` returns the following;

```
  1: /usr/share/vim/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syntax.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/synload.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syncolor.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim73/filetype.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim73/colors/kolor.vim
  7: /usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin.vim
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
  9: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/gzip.vim
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/matchparen.vim
 11: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 13: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/spellfile.vim
 14: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 15: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/tohtml.vim
 16: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 17: /usr/share/vim/vim73/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
```

The problem is, when I do the following, I get full sized tabs and no code folding;

```
touch example.rb
vi example.rb
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***NEVER*** do anything (add/remove/change) in `/usr/share/vim/` or `/etc/vim/`. ***NEVER.***

Those are runtime files:

- they are needed by Vim and modifying them puts Vim into an unstable state,
- they can be updated at the next upgrade, wiping your customization or parts of it out,
- they are available machine-wide, user-specific settings belong to the user's `$HOME`.

***ALWAYS*** do your customization in the `~/.vim/` directory and the `~/.vimrc` file.

- `/usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin/rb.vim` should be `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/ruby.vim`.
- In that file, you should use `setlocal` instead of `set` because filetype-specific settings should be as precise and local as possible.
- What you have put in `/etc/vim/vimrc` should be in `~/.vimrc`: you should remove those lines and return `/etc/vim/vimrc` back to its original state.
- Whatever else you have done in `/etc/vim/` or `/usr/share/vim`, revert it as soon as possible.

Comment: Additionally, it would be a good thing to keep your `~/.vimrc` and your `.vim` directory under revision control. So you can go back to a previous version in case you manage to really screw things up.

Comment: I originally put my files in `/etc/vim/`, as I wanted the configurations to be global. I assume a better way would to be create one in my home directory, and alias root's `~/.vim/` to it?

Comment: No. A better way is to never do anything as root unless it is strictly necessary. And if you *really* need to do serious editing with escalated privileges (why would anyone need that?) you should use `sudoedit`.